# Serialport missing data sent asynchronously

Tags: c#, serial-port

**Update:** I never did get C# code working for asynchronous serial responses, so I ended up using Python instead and translating the file to an exe and calling that from C#. Python handled the asynchronous responses fine and even calling it from C# didn't break it.

I'm communicating with a ublox modem in C# using a serial port provided over a USB interface. If I send a command I can get an expected response fine, but if there's a secondary, asynchronous response from the modem (e.g. connection event) I never see this second response when my code is running. I do see a connection response when I send the AT commands manually with Tera Term or when putting the serial port through a virtual COM port, so the data is being produced correctly. Any idea what might be causing my program to miss responses?

I'm running a console application and I've tried running in both Debug and Release. I've tried a few different options for the call to read the incoming data from the serial port including serialPort.ReadLine(), serialPort.ReadExisting(), serialPort.ReadBytes(), serialPort. serialPort.BaseStream.Read(), serialPort.BaseStream.ReadAsync(). None show any traffic coming through after the initial OK response. Most recent test code is below.

```cs
private static SerialPort serialPort;

static void Main(string[] args)
{
    serialPort = new SerialPort();
    serialPort.BaudRate = 115200;
    serialPort.Parity = Parity.None;
    serialPort.DataBits = 8;
    serialPort.StopBits = StopBits.One;
    serialPort.PortName = portName;
    serialPort.ReadTimeout = 500;
    serialPort.WriteTimeout = 500;
    serialPort.NewLine = "\r\n";
    serialPort.ReceivedBytesThreshold = 1;

    serialPort.Open();

    byte[] msg = new byte[100];

    string setServer = "AT+UFTP=1,\"<ftp_server>\"\r\n";
    Console.WriteLine(setServer);
    var task = serialPort.BaseStream.WriteAsync(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(setServer), 0, Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(setServer).Length);
    task.Wait();
    task = serialPort.BaseStream.ReadAsync(msg, 0, msg.Length);
    task.Wait();
    Console.WriteLine(Encoding.ASCII.GetString(msg));
    Thread.Sleep(1000);

    string setUser = "AT+UFTP=2,\"<user>\"\r\n";
    Console.WriteLine(setUser);
    task = serialPort.BaseStream.WriteAsync(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(setUser), 0, Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(setUser).Length);
    task.Wait();
    task = serialPort.BaseStream.ReadAsync(msg, 0, msg.Length);
    task.Wait();
    Console.WriteLine(Encoding.ASCII.GetString(msg));
    Thread.Sleep(1000);

    string setPassword = "AT+UFTP=3,\"<password>\"\r\n";
    Console.WriteLine(setPassword);
    task = serialPort.BaseStream.WriteAsync(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(setPassword), 0, Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(setPassword).Length);
    task.Wait();
    task = serialPort.BaseStream.ReadAsync(msg, 0, msg.Length);
    task.Wait();
    Console.WriteLine(Encoding.ASCII.GetString(msg));
    Thread.Sleep(1000);

    string setPort = "AT+UFTP=7,21\r\n";
    Console.WriteLine(setPort);
    task = serialPort.BaseStream.WriteAsync(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(setPort), 0, Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(setPort).Length);
    task.Wait();
    task = serialPort.BaseStream.ReadAsync(msg, 0, msg.Length);
    task.Wait();
    Console.WriteLine(Encoding.ASCII.GetString(msg));
    Thread.Sleep(1000);

    string set5 = "AT+UFTP=5,900\r\n";
    Console.WriteLine(set5);
    task = serialPort.BaseStream.WriteAsync(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(set5), 0, Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(set5).Length);
    task.Wait();
    task = serialPort.BaseStream.ReadAsync(msg, 0, msg.Length);
    task.Wait();
    Console.WriteLine(Encoding.ASCII.GetString(msg));
    Thread.Sleep(1000);

    string set6 = "AT+UFTP=6,1\r\n";
    Console.WriteLine(set6);
    task = serialPort.BaseStream.WriteAsync(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(set6), 0, Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(set6).Length);
    task.Wait();
    task = serialPort.BaseStream.ReadAsync(msg, 0, msg.Length);
    task.Wait();
    Console.WriteLine(Encoding.ASCII.GetString(msg));
    Thread.Sleep(1000);

    string connect = "AT+UFTPC=1\r\n";
    Console.WriteLine(connect);
    task = serialPort.BaseStream.WriteAsync(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(connect), 0, Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(connect).Length);
    task.Wait();

    while (true)
    {
         task = serialPort.BaseStream.ReadAsync(msg, 0, msg.Length);
         task.Wait();
         Console.WriteLine(Encoding.ASCII.GetString(msg));
    }
}
```

The output I see when I run the connection routine in Tera Term is below. When I run in C# I am seeing everything except for the last line (`+UUFTPCR: 1,1`).

```
at+uftp=1,"<ftp_server>"

OK
at+uftp=2,"<user>"

OK
at+uftp=3,"<password>"

OK
at+uftp=7,21

OK
at+uftp=5,900

OK
at+uftp=6,1

OK
at+uftpc=1

OK

+UUFTPCR: 1,1
```

Comment: Why do you `task.Wait()` when calling the async routines for `SerialPort`? You are basically doing async things synchronously, so really you can avoid the overhead (and possible deadlock) and just call `SerialPort.Write(...)`... I would also avoid writing directly to the `BaseStream` here and just use the the `SerialPort.Write(string)` methods.

Comment: I'm trying to keep the functions I'm using as close as possible to suggestions I've seen. I agree that using asynchronous functions this way doesn't make a ton of sense, it's just not something I'm concerned with right now. From what I've read (https://www.sparxeng.com/blog/software/must-use-net-system-io-ports-serialport), using the BaseStream objects are more reliable than using the serial port built in functions. In any case, switching to ```serialPort.Write()``` does not fix the problem I'm seeing.